# How are variables transmitted in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a function square which I would like to display a matrix like this:

```
XXX (newline)
XXX (newline)
XXX
```

My result is false after first line is printed. Why? How are variables transmitted in Prolog and how are the lines executed(order)?

```
line(Rez,X) :- Rez>=1 , write(X) , line(Rez-1,X).

square(N,X) :- Rez = N,line(Rez,X),nl,N>1,square(N-1,X).
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issue with your code. Notably, you're writing recursive predicate definitions without base cases. Another issue is that Prolog is not a functional language. When you write e.g. `line(Rez-1,X)`, Prolog is not going to evaluate `Rez-1` as an arithmetic expression. For Prolog, `Rez-1` is just a `'-'/2` compound term, i.e. a term with name `-` and two arguments. You will need to write something like `NextRez is Rez-1, line(NextRez,X)`. The `is/2` standard built-in predicate evaluates its second argument (as an arithmetic expression) and unifies the resulting with the first argument.